# Using the primary key as a foreign key

Tags: database-design, mysql, relational-database

I have data spread across two tables `shipments` and `shipment_data`. Currently I have the standard auto increment primary key `id` for `shipments` and a manually assigned unique primary key `id` for `shipment_data`. The primary key on `shipment_data` is also a foreign key referencing id on `shipments`.

In my mind this seems more efficient than making `shipment_data.id` auto increment and adding a `shipment_data.shipment_id` foreign key, since they will, as long as everything works correctly, have the same value as both will be created at the same time.

But I have a creeping feeling that there might be something I'm overlooking.

Comment: This is a known pattern if you have a 1:0..1 relationship. But if the relationship is 1:1 you should maybe consider if you even need two separate tables.

Comment: Just to be sure that I do not misunderstand: 1) you create shipments and get the auto-incremented shipment.id 2) you copy shipment.id into shipment_data.id, so that from the point of view of their value, the primary keys are equal for two corresponding records ?

Comment: @Christophe yes, that is correct

Comment: @JacquesB shipment_data contains a bunch varaible length of json fields whereas everything in shipments is fixed width. Both are created simultaneously but there is often no need to query both. Whether or not I should have seperated the tables is another thing I'm somewhat concerned about but it's a separate question.

Comment: Ideally your application would always, *always*, specify what fields you query. See [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/402022). Baring that, you can create multiple views over a single table.

Comment: Look up the buzzword "shared primary key".  It's a useful technique in some situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Foreign key mapping](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/foreignKeyMapping.html) is a proven technique for implementing a one-to-many relationship (not mandatory, i.e.  `1 - 0..*`).  So having a foreign key in `shipment_data` that refers to `shipment`'s primary key `shipment.id` would allow no, one, or many `shipment_data` for a specific `shipment`.

Using the foreign key as a primary key is possible.  It requires you to first create the a `shipment` then the `shipment_data` reusing the same id, and it structurally constrains the relationship to an one-to-one (not mandatory, i.e. `1 - 0..1`).

This is a reasonable solution, if you are sure that the relationship shall not evolve to become one-to-many.  It also works in case `shipment_data` creation could be delayed (for example if the `shipment` is first planned, and `shipment_data` would only be  filled once the final package weight was measured and the parcel tracking number was issued by the carrier).

Comment: `if you are sure that the relationship shall not evolve to become one-to-many` it's pretty simple to migrate this into one-to-many relationship. If you end up needing this relationship to be one-to-many, you can just duplicate the column, convert the primary key column to be autoincrement, and adjust the foreign key constraint.

Comment: @LieRyan yes, I agree. You just have to make sure that you spot hidden assumptions of key sharing in sql queries. I was thinking also from an operational point of view, since you’ll have to schedule a downtime for your system, run the db script, and deploy your new version (is it on a central node, or does it run on many remote nodes?) before you get it up and running again.  Nothing complex, but depending on the architecture, a little more risky to organise compared to having already the column and just relaxing the constraint on how it is used.